# The method "findById" is not working, even though I am providing the correct Object Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am sending a PUT request to my local host

```
http://localhost:3000/vidly.com/api/genres/5e87a056ee45fc0b300569c8
```

My code for the PUT route handler is :-

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = genreValidation(req.body);

  if (result.error) {
    return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
  }

  console.log(req.params.id);
  const genre = await Genres.findById(req.param.id);
  console.log(genre);
  if (!genre)
    return res.status(404).send(`Bro, we dont have any genre of such Id..`);

 genre.set({
    genreName: req.body.genreName,
  });
  await genre.save();
  console.log(genre);
  return res.send(genre);
});
```

I have used findByIdAndUpdate() , findOne() methods but in all cases, my PUT request is not working and genre constant is always NULL !

Comment: Try `const genre = await Genres.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.param.id));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could just comment this, but I don't have enough reputation:

Are you sure using `req.param.id` is correct, versus `req.params.id` with the 's' at the end of 'param'? You're using the plural in the `console.log` above, but not in the `findById` method

```js
  //this is correct
  console.log(req.params.id);
  //I don't think this is without the 's'
  const genre = await Genres.findById(req.param.id);
```